# How can you tell if Chrome Custom Tabs is correctly prefetching after calling mayLaunchUrl?

Tags: android, prefetch, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm using chrome custom tabs with `mayLaunchUrl` for prefetching. I tried using chrome inspect to find evidence of the prefetch but nothing is coming up on there. I confirmed that `mayLaunchUrl` is returning true. However, I'm skeptical on whether the prefetch is actually happening as the loading of the web page is slower than I expected.

**Is there a way for me to confirm that the prefetch is actually happening?**